# Disproving differentiability of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm supposed to verify the following statement:

$$f(z)=\Re (z)\;\implies\;\not\exists\;z\in\mathbb C:\;\exists\;f'(z)\subseteq\mathbb C$$

My idea was to note the following for some $z=x+iy$

$$\frac{z+\bar z}{2}=\Re(z)$$

We rewrite $f$ with this identity:

$$f(z)=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}=x$$

Consider the following:

$$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$

$$\implies u(x,y)=x\;\;\text{and}\;\;v(x,y)=0$$

Cauchy-Reimann equations tell us that if $f$ is differentiable, then $u_x=v_y$.

However, $u_x=1$ and $v_y=0$.

This implies $f$ isn't differentiable for all $z\in\mathbb C$.

Does this work?

Comment: That is it.  Complex differentiable requires continuous partial derivatives that satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: @DougM Dope thanks